# Execution Plan Cost

Tags: sql, postgresql

What does this mean?

```
cost=0.11..288531.38
```

Does that mean the cost is between 0.11 and 288,531.38? That's a huge range...too big to be useful, so just want to be sure.

Comment: That's not a range. It's [explained in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-BASICS): the first number is the startup cost, the second the overall cost. Getting the first row will be fast but getting all results will be very slow

Comment: Thanks, post that as the answer so I can mark it as so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a range. As [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-BASICS) explain:

> The numbers that are quoted in parentheses are (left to right):
>
> - Estimated start-up cost. This is the time expended before the output phase can begin, e.g., time to do the sorting in a sort node.
> - Estimated total cost. This is stated on the assumption that the plan node is run to completion, i.e., all available rows are retrieved. In practice a node's parent node might stop short of reading all available rows....
> - Estimated number of rows output by this plan node. Again, the node is assumed to be run to completion.
> - Estimated average width of rows output by this plan node (in bytes).

That means the operator with cost `0.11..288531.38` has a small startup cost but a high overall cost.